# Selenium 4.11.2 not able to use enableVNC option while it is working for Selenium 4.1.0

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium and python 3.9.6 to automate the tests on GUI. I have enabled 'enableVNC' option for chrome for viewing virtual machine and its working fine for Selenium 4.1.0 and chrome 116. When upgrading to selenium 4.11.2 I can't set `enableVNC` to True.

Current code

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['enableVNC']=True
driver = webdriver.Remote(self.hub_url, options=option)
```

Does someone know how to set it to "True" or is this option changes or deprecated ?
Also can you help how to set screen resolution to "1920*1080" for headless chrome ?

I tried all the setting the it using add_options, experimental options but it crashes the code. This time it didn't crash the code but neither it started the VNC.

Answer (score 0):

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['selenoid:options'] = {'enableVNC': True}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=remote_server, options=options)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).